# Automatically remove instance from ELB on server stop

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, chkconfig

How to automatically remove an instance from its LoadBalance (ELB) when you stop the instance?

I've tried to create a shutdown script and put it on chkconfig, but it is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
# loggly authorization 
#
# chkconfig: 2345 20 10
# description: add host logs to loggly
# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions
. /etc/profile.d/aws-apitools-common.sh

LB=MyLB
OK="\033[60G\e[0;32mOK\e[0m"
EC2_INSTANCE_ID="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id || die \"wget instance-id has failed: $?\"`"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default

start() {
    echo "started service"
}

stop() {
        echo "removing $EC2_INSTANCE_ID from Load Balancer"
        elb-deregister-instances-from-lb $LB --instances=$EC2_INSTANCE_ID -I $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -S $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --quiet
        sleep 20
}


restart() {
        stop
        sleep 5
        start
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  restart)
        restart
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
esac

exit $?
```

Comment: Try specifying the path to `wget`, `elb-deregister-instances-from-lb`, etc., as it's probably running with a minimal default `$PATH`.

Comment: nothing... I did a simple command: `echo "test" >/test.txt` 
and the file test.txt does not exists after I start the server again...

Comment: That could be the same thing. As your normal user, do `which echo`, then use that explicit path to test. It's probably something like `/bin/echo`.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a `/var/lock/subsys/my_app` file

Put a `touch /var/lock/subsys/my_app` in the startup function and
 a `rm /var/lock/subsys/my_app` in the stop function